# Highcharts does not display years on Xaxis when data with NULL values

Tags: highcharts, null, axis

I am having an issue with Highcharts not wanting to display the years in my column chart when there is another series with only NULL values. It just display "1,2,3,4..." instead of "2000,2001,2002,....".
The data for the series are being generated on the fly - and should appear in the legend. Looks like this then:
[image]

If I delete the »empty« series, it's correctly displayed. So, somehow, it must perhaps consider the second (»empty«) series instead of the first one?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var options =
    {
        chart:
        {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            marginTop: 70,
            zoomType:'xy',
            marginBottom: 85,
            events:
            {
                load: function ()
                {
                    var chart = this,
                    yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
                    firstLabel = yAxis.ticks[yAxis.tickPositions[0]].labelBBox.width,
                    lastLabel = yAxis.ticks[yAxis.tickPositions[yAxis.tickAmount - 1]].labelBBox.width,
                    bb = yAxis.axisTitle.getBBox();
                    yAxis.update
                    ({
                        title: 
                        {
                            offset: -bb.width + 20 + (firstLabel > lastLabel ? firstLabel : lastLabel) //make sure that will be enough space for yAxis labels
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        xAxis:
        {
            categories:[],
            tickInterval: 1,
            tickLength: 0,
            showLastLabel: true
        },
        legend:
        {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderColor: '#EEE',
            floating: false,
            align: 'center',
            x: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            y: -20
        },
        plotOptions:
        {   
            series:
            {
                lineWidth: 2,
                shadow: false,
                marker:
                {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        series: []
    };


    $.get('data.csv', function(data)
    {
        // Split the lines
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line)
        {
            var items = line.split(',');

            // header line containes series name
            if (lineNo === 0)
            {
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item)
                {
                    if (itemNo > 0)
                    {
                        if (item == 'xxx')
                        {
                            options.series.push(
                            {
                                name:item,
                                lineWidth: 5, 
                                data:[],
                                connectNulls: true
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            options.series.push(
                            {
                                name:item,
                                data:[],
                                connectNulls: true
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
            else
            {
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item)
                {
                    if(itemNo == 0)
                    {
                                                            }
                    else if (item == "null")
                    {
                        options.series[itemNo-1].data.push(null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        options.series[itemNo-1].data.push(parseFloat(item));
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

The CSV data:

```
Years,Africa,World (No data available)
2000,14.3405162298653740,null
2001,null,null
2002,null,null
2003,23.1953563661334879,null
2004,null,null
2005,null,null
2006,null,null
2007,11.9915962677369679,null
```

The jsfiddle demo is working (unfortunately) correctly. https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/en2bmutp/3/

Any hints?

Comment: JSFiddle with the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/t3sxmvub/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't set categories, or keep track of them anywhere in your code as far as I can see. There are many options for how you can solve this. I prefer adding categories to the data points. Which can be done like this (only showing your last else clause):

```
else {
  var currentX = 0; //Added this
  $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
    if (itemNo == 0) {
      currentX = parseInt(item) //Added this to get year
    } else if (item == "null") {
      options.series[itemNo - 1].data.push({
        x: currentX, //added object
        y: null
      }); //Added object
    } else {
      options.series[itemNo - 1].data.push({
        x: currentX,  //added object
        y: parseFloat(item)
      }); 
    }
  });
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = {
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'column',
      marginTop: 70,
      zoomType: 'xy',
      marginBottom: 85,
      events: {
        load: function() {
          var chart = this,
            yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
            firstLabel = yAxis.ticks[yAxis.tickPositions[0]].labelBBox.width,
            lastLabel = yAxis.ticks[yAxis.tickPositions[yAxis.tickAmount - 1]].labelBBox.width,
            bb = yAxis.axisTitle.getBBox();
          yAxis.update({
            title: {
              offset: -bb.width + 20 + (firstLabel > lastLabel ? firstLabel : lastLabel) //make sure that will be enough space for yAxis labels
            }
          });
        }
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [],
      tickInterval: 1,
      tickLength: 0,
      showLastLabel: true
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'horizontal',
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      borderColor: '#EEE',
      floating: false,
      align: 'center',
      x: 0,
      verticalAlign: 'bottom',
      y: -20
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        lineWidth: 2,
        shadow: false,
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    },
    series: []
  };

  function addSeries() {
    var data = document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
      var items = line.split(',');

      // header line containes series name
      if (lineNo === 0) {
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
          if (itemNo > 0) {
            if (item == 'xxx') {
              options.series.push({
                name: item,
                lineWidth: 5,
                data: [],
                connectNulls: true
              });
            } else {
              options.series.push({
                name: item,
                data: [],
                connectNulls: true
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
      // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
      else {
        var currentX = 0; //Added this
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
          if (itemNo == 0) {
            currentX = parseInt(item) //Added this
          } else if (item == "null") {
            options.series[itemNo - 1].data.push({
              x: currentX,
              y: null
            }); //Added object
          } else {
            options.series[itemNo - 1].data.push({
              x: currentX,
              y: parseFloat(item)
            }); //added object
          }
        });
      }
    });
    console.log(options)
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  }
  addSeries();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<pre id="csv" style="display:none">Years,Africa,World (No data available)
2000,14.3405162298653740,null
2001,null,null
2002,null,null
2003,23.1953563661334879,null
2004,null,null
2005,null,null
2006,null,null
2007,11.9915962677369679,null
</pre>
```

Other ways to solve the problem is adding the categories to the xAxis, or setting [`pointStart`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointStart). However, the way I have shown above will account for multiple series with differing dates.

**Working JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/t3sxmvub/8/